# Promise.all with $q promise and JS event loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, es6-promise, angular-promise, event-loop

Let's say I have the following code in empty AngularJS controller:

```
Promise.all([Promise.resolve()]).then(() => console.log('Then'));
setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout callback'));
```

I expect:

1. `Promise.all.then` will be put into the event loop.
2. `setTimeout` callback will be put into the event loop.

We don't make any long requests and there should be the following output:
`Then`
`setTimeout callback`
And it works.

But if we replace `Promise.resolve()` by `$q.resolve()`:

```
Promise.all([$q.resolve()]).then(() => console.log('Then'));
setTimeout(() => console.log('setTimeout callback'));
```

the output will be different:
`setTimeout callback`
`Then`

Here is a plunk: https://embed.plnkr.co/0h0i4CzuSgqMbYQtxZtU/
Why is the output different? How does `$q.resolve` affect the output?

Comment: They are asynchronous callbacks, there is no order to them. Also you should be using `$q.all` and `$timeout` instead

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons:

- `Promise.all` doesn't "detect" already-fulfilled promises, and returns an immediately resolved promise because of that. It always *waits* for its input promises, using their `.then()` method (also it needs to assimilate non-native promises through this anyway). Since `then` callbacks are always asynchronous, the `Promise.all(…)` result always is resolved asynchronously (unless the iterable is empty), and the `Promise.all(…).then(…)` callback is scheduled later
- There is not a single event queue on the event loop, but multiple ones for different sources. So even if the promise things take more "ticks" of the event loop, their queue is simply served more often than, and before, the timeout queue.
- We don't know what mechanism `$q` is using for making its promise callbacks asynchronous. We only know that it's not the native promise one, and therefore using a different, apparently "slower", queue.

In general, you cannot (should not) rely on asynchronous callbacks to be called in any specific order, except their documentation mentions it. Make the ordering explicit (e.g. using promises) when you need it.